# How do you return a timestamp from setTimezone function?

Tags: php, php-carbon

I want to be able to convert the current UTC time to a user's timezone, and get the value as a timestamp. Simple.

I seem to be having some difficulty though... this is what I've tried:

```
Carbon::now()->setTimezone('America/Los_Angeles'); // this works, but returns the time in the format "Y-m-d H:i:s"
```

So then I tried this:

```
Carbon::now()->setTimezone('America/Los_Angeles')->timestamp; // for some reason doing this seems to revert the timezone conversion and instead returns the timestamp for the current UTC time? :/
```

So, I'm using this workaround:

```
    $converted_time = Carbon::now()->setTimezone('America/Los_Angeles');
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $converted_time)->timestamp;
```

...which gives me what I need, but seems unnecessary. Is there a better way to do this (in one line)?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the expected result? Why do yon eed this to be in one line?

Answer (score 0):

The Unix Timestamp is per definition the number of second since 1st January 1970 UTC.

If you're trying to calculate the number of second since an other date (like 1st January in Los Angeles), you're calculating something else that is not Unix Timestamp.

Your code:

```
Carbon::now()->setTimezone($tz)->timestamp
```

Will always return the same value for a given moment whatever is `$tz` which is the expected behavior, no bug here, timestamp is not timezone-dependent.

To make sense, it's very important that the timestamp as a number would be a non-ambigus representation of a single second that can be used safely worldwide and still represent the same moment. If you have a number that can be different moment regarding from which timezone you're looking at it, you're likely not using the right tool, and would get more safety to store date-time + timezone.

So the very first question, is why would you need to get the number of second since 1st January in Los Angeles?

You can read more in this post of mine about how to properly work with UTC and why to avoid having a strong dependence in your back-end with calculations in other timezones:

https://kylekatarnls.medium.com/always-use-utc-dates-and-times-8a8200ca3164

Comment: Thanks for your answer: I understand what you're saying about the definition of `timestamp` and that it is inextricably linked to UTC. Perhaps then I'm not using the correct terminology, but to answer your question "why would you need to get the number of second since 1st January in Los Angeles?"-- the reason is that I'm using a Javascript clock plugin on the front end that takes a {{{timestamp}}} from the server to initialize the clock with a given timezone. FYI, [this is the plugin in question](https://github.com/JohnRDOrazio/jQuery-Clock-Plugin#custom-server-generated-timestamp)

Comment: I will also add that the workaround that I stated I'm using in my question *does* actually work; it gives the output I need, and it works with the plugin. So to answer this I guess I'd need to know how I should be handling this instead of what I'm currently doing?

Comment: The standard way to exchange dates is ISO-8601, timezone is explicit in those string and JS handle it natively with `new Date(iso8601String)`. If some library us a non-standard/ambigus input format, a good thing is to propose a pull-request to this library to support standards. As a last resort, create an adapter, basically JS side: `(new Date(iso8601String)).getTime()` would works fine as timezone is yet shifted by browser.

Comment: This solution is actually a real internationalization because you get the user timezone instead of an hard-coded or re-calculated timezone in the back-end like `America/Los_Angeles`, timezone is a client thing, you should have as few timezones as possible on the back-end side (keep UTC as long as possible).

Comment: Thanks, @KyleK. Afaict the plugin doesn't accept ISO-8601. I've refined this a bit so that I extract the timezone offset using Carbon's `getOffset()` which gives me the number of seconds to add or substract to the Unix Timestamp (which I get from `Carbon::now()`). So now I pass `$timestamp + $tzoffset` to my front end. This just gives the same number as I had before, although I think my methodology is now more 'correct'? I guess this is about terminology/semantics. ie. timestamp + tzoffset = x. Perhaps this number `x`, should be called a "timezone-adjusted timestamp" rather than a timestamp??

Comment: I note that doing the timestamp + tzoffset calculation to get a localised {{timestamp}} can't be completely unorthodox; what other reason would there be for Carbon's `getOffset()` method?

Comment: I don't really get what you did, but it sounds like you will force every uses to Los Angeles timezone, while doing the conversion from JS side would handle properly the timezone of any user. You should change your OS timezone (keeping Los Angeles on the back end) and double-check it really behave as you expect.

Comment: All that is not about terminology but having your app working in any place making your code reusable.
Second: the plugin allow you to set the server time so you could easily set any proper timestamp to make both the reference and the clock both in UTC.

Comment: Please remove the link to your blog and add some more details about how resolve the problem with PHP code

Comment: There is no correct "code solution" to this problem, because it's based on the incorrect assertion that timestamp value is timezone-dependent while it's not.

`Carbon::now()->setTimezone($tz)->timestamp` will always return the same value at a given moment whatever is `$tz` the whole question should be removed IMO as it could encourage other devs to take a wrong direction for their date-exchange systems.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it

Comment: It really sounds like my answer now says the same thing in 3 different ways, but fine, I added it. 